# Randomizing select distinct

Tags: java, sql-server

We use multiple databases at work, at least Oracle and MSSQL.  Not sure why we have to use both but this question is about MSSQL.

There is a table, let's just call it System..DirectMapping that has a field accountID. I can't guarantee they are all numeric, but they appear to be.

So really my question is in two related parts.

First, I have to find a valid account id.  That is one that is in the table.  This is straight forward, but I would like to get a random one.

So I did a

```
select distinct accountID from System..DirectMapping
```

which works but they are always in the same order.  I read how you could randomize something using newid() so I tried

```
 select distinct accountID from System..DirectMapping order by newid()
```

but it gave me an error that when selecting distinct, the order by field must occur in the select which would not make sense here.  So I tried

```
 select accountID from
 (select distinct accountID from System..DirectMapping) j
 order by newid()
```

but it gave me a similar error about not being able to order by in views.  I finally just read the whole thing into a java array and did a Collections.shuffle() but it would be better to do it from the query because then I could limit the number of results (I think like top 10..).  So is there any way to do that?

I will save the second question for later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do an ORDER BY in a view if you use a TOP specification:

```
 select TOP 100 PERCENT accountID from
 (select distinct accountID from System..DirectMapping) j
 order by newid()
```

Comment: A minor suggestion: since the object is to select a single random `accountID`, how about `top 1` instead of `top 100 percent`?